# React Component not updating {CountdownCircleTimer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, timer

Basically, i have two buttons **"START"** and **"PAUSE"**, when i click the start, the **CountDownCircleTimer** starts, but when i clicked "PAUSE" it is not stopping!

Can anyone please help me with this? I am new to react. Thanks in advance!

```
checkDisplay() {
    let display = this.state.display
    let displayMode;
    let playing;
    if (!display) {

  displayMode =
    <div align='center'>
      <input name='duration' size='10' value={this.state.duration} onChange={this.checkInt}></input>
    </div>
}
else {

  //const time=this.state.duration*60
  displayMode = <div align='center'>

    <CountdownCircleTimer
//This 'ISPLAYING' is not working as expected!
      isPlaying={this.state.isPaused ? false : true}
      duration={this.state.duration * 60}
      colors={[['#004777', 0.33], ['#F7B801', 0.33], ['#A30000']]}
    >

      {({ elapsedTime }) => this.renderTime(this.state.Min, this.state.Sec)}

    </CountdownCircleTimer>
  </div>
}
return displayMode;


}

  render() {

return (
  <div className="App">
    <div>
      <p>{this.state.text}</p>
      <div>
        {this.checkDisplay()}
          </div>
)
}
```

Comment: please uptate a question with at least an entire `render` method

Comment: @poltorin hey, updated the question! please help me if you can. Thank you :)

Comment: I still don't see any buttons, which may help to understand what method is triggered